# problem with relative path to .js file in ASP.net ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager, user-controls

I'm working with an ASP.net web application.

I've written a user control called `LocationSelector` that has its own Javascript in an external .js file.  In order to load that file, I use the following line of code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, typeof(LocationSelector), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Controls/LocationSelector.js");
```

The problem is with `"Controls/LocationSelector.js"`.  As long as the page that uses the control is in the root directory of the application, everything works.  However, as soon as I try to put this control in a page in a subdirectory, it can't load the Javascript file.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but off the top of my head I would say you need something along the lines of this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this, typeof(LocationSelector), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/Controls/LocationSelector.js"));
```

Comment: This seems to work.  You did miss a "/" though, after the "~".  I fixed that for you.